# ansi escape codes interface/non-hardcoded mapping

Tags: bash, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

bash has support for ansi escape codes. i would like to use fancy and pretty printing of some test in a script. since i didn't find any basic builtin\lib\tool\script that provide this functionality, it seems that i have to use a hardcoded mapping between names and escape codes, e.g.

```bash
RESET="0"
BOLD="1"
FAINT="2"
ITALIC="3"
# etc.
FG_RED="31"
BG_RED="41"
```

is there any builtin\lib\tool\script that gives a simple interface/tool/lib/etc. to use ansi colors and effect in bash? if not, how can i retrieve the mapping somehow?

Comment: No, don't hard-code terminal-specific escapes like that.  Always use `tput` to get the correct code (if any) for the actual terminal type.

Answer (score 2):

I usually drop something like this in at the top of my scripts..

```bash
# print color (no previous dependency on setting colors)
#---------------------------------
# color formatting and stuff
#---------------------------------
# print a string in color, with no \n
# e.g. printcn red "some text"
printcn() {
  local m="${*:-$(read -t 0.01 m; echo "${m}")}"
  #local m="${@}"
  local c="${m%% *}"  # color would be in first word
  # see if first word (lowercase) matches a color
  case "${c,,}" in
    -n|nc|norm|normal) m="$(tput sgr0   )${m#* }" ;;
    -r|red)            m="$(tput setaf 1)${m#* }" ;;
    -g|grn|green)      m="$(tput setaf 2)${m#* }" ;;
    -y|yel|yellow)     m="$(tput setaf 3)${m#* }" ;;
    -b|blu|blue)       m="$(tput setaf 4)${m#* }" ;;
    -m|mag|magenta)    m="$(tput setaf 5)${m#* }" ;;
    -c|cya|cyan)       m="$(tput setaf 6)${m#* }" ;;
    -w|whi|white)      m="$(tput setaf 7)${m#* }" ;;
  esac
  printf -- '%s' "${m}$(tput sgr0)"
} >&2

# Print color with newline
printc() {
  local in
  in="${*:-$(read -t 0.01 in; echo "${in}")}"
  printcn "${in}"; printf '\n'
} >&2
```

Then I can do things like this:

```bash
printc -r this is red text
printc blue "This is blue"
```

[image]

Take a look at (https://github.com/kigster/bashmatic) or a script like this: [bashmatic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kigster/bashmatic/main/bin/bashmatic-install)

Comment: thank you. as stated clearly in my question, i am not looking into hardcoded values as you have.

Comment: I am just wrapping functions around tput - have you looked into `tput`? The "pretty" printing you are looking for in bash doesn't exist - you have to use a tool like tput, use the ansi codes as you have, etc. Check out https://techstop.github.io/bash-script-colors/

Comment: Or look into using python - python has some good cli libraries - something like https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/ or python click, typer, or others modules - otherwise, you are looking at tput, custom functions, or ansi codes in bash.

Comment: thank you. as stated clearly, i am interested in bash.